# Get ETH Wallet address list by smart contract address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I would like to fetch the list of all ETH wallet addresses by an API(?), given a smart contract address.
Similar feature that we see on etherscan.io under the erc20 Holder list. Any docs/resource would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the addresses of all accounts from which transactions were sent to a specific smart contract, then the only general  way is to scan all blocks using the **eth_getBlockByNumber** method (or its equivalent) and "manually" select all transactions with the desired recipient address.

At the same time, you also most likely need to weed out transactions coming from other smart contracts. In order to determine whether an address belongs to an account or a smart contract, you can, for example, use the **eth_getCode** method - if it returns an empty value, then this is an account.